# How to save current input.value while typing, into a new global variable?

Tags: javascript

how do i save the input.value while typing into a new variable(currentInput) so that i can use that new variable globally?

```
HTML code:
```

```html
        <h1>Check if your text is a Palindrome:</h1>
        <div id="palindrome-checker">
          <p>Enter your text</p>
          <form id="palindrome-form">
            <input type="text" id="text-input" required value="">
            <button type="button" id="check-btn" >Enter</button>
          </form>
```

```
Javascript code:
```

```js
       const input = document.querySelector("#text-input");
       const button = document.querySelector("#check-btn");
       const output = document.querySelector("#result");
       const form  = document.querySelector("#palindrome-form");
       let currentInput = "";

       
       input.onkeyup = myFunction
  
      function myFunction(){
        currentInput = document.querySelector("#text-input").value 
      }
```

Comment: for a start, don't make `currentInput` a **const** since you can't change a `const` - add a handler for the `input` event of the `<input>` that reads its `value`

Comment: can i ask how to do that im a beginner im sorry, i wanted to do .onkeyup and save each pressed letter to currentInput like:                                                                                       input.onkeyup then save it into currentInput

Comment: my suggestion was to use `oninput`

Answer (score 0):

So, this would be the straight forward answer: You can listen for the input event on the input element and update the variable `currentInput`:

```js
const form = document.forms.palindrome_form;
let currentInput = "";

form.text_input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  currentInput = e.target.value;
  console.log(currentInput);
});
```

```html
<h1>Check if your text is a Palindrome:</h1>
<div id="palindrome_checker">
  <p>Enter your text</p>
  <form id="palindrome_form">
    <input type="text" id="text_input" required value="">
    <button type="button" id="check_btn">Enter</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

But, why have that extra variable when there is already a variable with the value. From anywhere in you JavaScript code you can ask for: `form.text_input.value`. That said, I guess you would like to update something when the value change. To either just add more event listeners:

```js
const form = document.forms.palindrome_form;

form.text_input.addEventListener('input', update_output);
form.text_input.addEventListener('input', test_palindrome);

function update_output(e){
  e.target.form.output.value = e.target.value;
}

function test_palindrome(e) {
  let str = e.target.value;
  if (str.length > 2) {
    let str2 = str.split("").reverse().join("");
    if (str == str2) {
      console.log('Palindrome!');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Check if your text is a Palindrome:</h1>
<div id="palindrome_checker">
  <p>Enter your text</p>
  <form id="palindrome_form">
    <input type="text" id="text_input" required value="">
    <button type="button" id="check_btn">Enter</button>
    <output name="output"></output>
  </form>
</div>
```

Or create a custom event when the value updates:

```js
const form = document.forms.palindrome_form;

form.text_input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let event = new CustomEvent('textInput', {detail: e.target.value});
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
});

document.addEventListener('textInput', update_output);
document.addEventListener('textInput', test_palindrome);

function update_output(e){
  form.output.value = e.detail;
}

function test_palindrome(e) {
  let str = e.detail;
  if (str.length > 2) {
    let str2 = str.split("").reverse().join("");
    if (str == str2) {
      console.log('Palindrome!');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Check if your text is a Palindrome:</h1>
<div id="palindrome_checker">
  <p>Enter your text</p>
  <form id="palindrome_form">
    <input type="text" id="text_input" required value="">
    <button type="button" id="check_btn">Enter</button>
    <output name="output"></output>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe this would be better code:

```js
       const input = document.querySelector("#text-input");
       const button = document.querySelector("#check-btn");
       const output = document.querySelector("#result");
       const form  = document.querySelector("#palindrome-form");
       let currentInput = "";

       
       input.addEventListener("input", myFunction)
  
      function myFunction(){
        currentInput = input.value 
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried that? `currentInput` will not actually be *current* - `keyup` would be better - but `input` would also handle other ways of entering data

Comment: @JaromandaX perhaps event `input` or `keypress` would be better

Comment: no, as I said, `input` or `keyup` - both `keydown` and `keypress` suffer the same inconsistency - i.e. the value is one keystroke behind

Comment: @JaromandaX `keypress` works fine I have used it in my websites. it works well with even special keyboards better than `input`

Comment: maybe different browsers work different ... try it in your answer here - none of my browsers do what **you** expect ... and `input` lets you drag text into the input, or right-click paste ... none of the `key*` events let you see that